# When using Citrus <TestMessage> child tag of <payload> element I am getting the following error

Tags: java, citrus-framework

```
 cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 
'TestMessage'. One of '{WC[##other:"http://www.citrusframework.org/schema/
  testcase"]}' is expected.
```

Here is the screen shot XML dsl file [click here to see xml image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbyNa.png) of citrus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `<TestMessage>` is not using any namespace. This is not allowed in payload element. You should use a proper XML namespace or go with `<data>` element instead of `<payload>`.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer in case it helped you solve the problem? Thx